# C# Xna Noise for terrain-generation

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, noise, terrain

I struggle making my own map generator, generating 2d maps like in terraria. My problem is that the result of [this](http://ploobs.com.br/?p=1742) looks very unnatural (the caves are mostly really big and round) while the [open source simplex noise](http://code.google.com/p/simplexnoise/source/browse/trunk/SimplexNoise/Noise.cs) makes nice long and natural caves when i put it where in the first link the getSmoothNoise(x,y) is located.

Now i have some questions:

1. is it correct that the simplex noise is already interpolated but not smoothed?
2. does the getSmoothNoise method only smooth the noise or is it also interpolating it?
3. why is the perlin noise algorithm from the link faster than the simplex noise, when i blend multiple octaves of the noises together? I thought simplex is faster?

What i actually want to do is creating many noises with the size of my map. Each ore/resoource would get its own noise then and in the end i would blend them all together.

1. can you imagine a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just link you to what you really want, which is a c# port of the Accidental Noise Library:

http://discordgames.com/?p=1954

Accidental Noise:

http://accidentalnoise.sourceforge.net/

This library will give you a much better way at creating maps that will lay ores in more specific areas.